# Pluging an Adafruit touchscreen on a HifiBerry DAC+

Tags: gpio, pi-2, pitft, hifiberry

I'm trying to connect a [Adafruit PiTFT 2.8" TFT 320x240+](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2423) touchscreen and a [HifiBerry DAC+](https://www.hifiberry.com/dacplus) on a Raspberry Pi 2 B. Is it possible? Do I need to solder the touchscreen card on the DAC+?

[image: Adafruit touchscreen and HifiBerry DAC+]

Comment: I would even be interested in how to use the holes next to the GPIO connectors on the 2 HATs. Do I need to solder a header or can I find some solution without soldering (and voiding the warranties)?